# TestNG, running different tests depending on version of application

Tags: maven, parameters, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

Question: how to execute different tests from the same test suite, depending on parameter sent from Jenkins (version)?

Background: have application and 5 versions of it.
The difference between them is small, but exist and it is implemented in testcases.
So I have group of testcases which are the same from version to version and I have groups of test cases which are different from version to version.

What by Boss wants: we should be able to select application version number in Jenkins right in the same place where we selecting against which server to execute and what browser to use.
So I have in my text.xml

```
<suite name="aaaa">
        <parameter name="SiteAddress" value="${SiteAddress}"/>
        <parameter name="Version" value="${version}"/>
```

in POM.xml

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
     <SiteAddress>${serv_url}</SiteAddress>
     <browser>${browser}</browser>
     <Version>${version}</Password>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Question again:
what is pattern to switch test cases depending of parameter value?
I just can't figure it out how to implement it.
Thank you!

Comment: depending on parameter value of version, you want a particular group of cases to execute, is that what your requirement is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I implemented a worflow in Jenkins by creating testng xml programmatically and use the command line args for filtering tests for execution.

Jenkins calls Ant build.xml which in turn calls the Java class, where I create testng xml programmatically and the command line args are passed from jenkins > ant > java class. Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Thank you, I would dig in. Really appreciate for you answer.